# The last nested array is lost when an object is created accordingly mongoose model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to create an object according to my model in mongoose using a controller, but I'm running into a problem that the last array nesting with prize patterns is not being written. Theoretically it is, but it is empty. I do not understand what the problem is, since I cannot add the necessary value to it even after creating the object through the constructor and after that doing something like: newGame.prizes = prizes;
With this behavior, all other properties within the prize property appear in the object, but the pattern array is empty.

Here is what my model looks like:

```
const GameSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  type: String,
  roundId: String,
  userId: String,
  calloutNumbersCount: Number,
  tickets: [
    {
      id: String,
      columns: [[Number]],
    },
  ],
  prizes: [
    {
      id: String,
      name: String,
      nameLocaleKey: String,
      winAmount: Number,
      patterns: [
        {
          type: String,
          count: Number,
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
  ticketPrice: Number,
  boughtTicketIds: [String],
  ended: Boolean,
});
```

Controller:

```
function createGame(gameType, userId) {
  const currentGameConfig = config[gameType];
  console.log("Controller");
  currentGameConfig.prizes.map((el) => console.log(el.patterns));
  const roundId = nanoid(LENGTH_OF_ROUND_ID);
  const game = new Game({
    type: currentGameConfig.type,
    roundId,
    userId,
    calloutNumbersCount: currentGameConfig.callout.numbersCount,
    tickets: [
      {
        id: 123, // temp
        columns: [[0]], // temp
      },
    ],
    prizes: currentGameConfig.prizes,
    ticketPrice: currentGameConfig.tickets.price,
    boughtTicketIds: ["1", "2"], // temp
    ended: false,
  });

  return game;
}
```

Place of creation and modification of the object in the route:

```
if (!game) {
      const newGame = gameController.createGame(type, userId);
      // newGame.prizes = currentGameConfig.prizes;

      Game.addGame(newGame, (err, game) => {

        if (err) {
          res.json({ success: false, message: err.message });
          throw err;
        }
        return res.json({
          roundId: newGame.roundId,
        });
      });
    }
```

Expected result:

[image]

The result:
[image]

**EDITED**

CurrentGameConfig:

```
{
  type: 'BINGO_75',
  name: 'Bingo 75',
  nameLocaleKey: 'GAMES.BINGO_75',
  prizes: [
    {
      name: 'Prize 1',
      nameLocaleKey: 'PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_1',
      winAmount: 10,
      patterns: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Prize 2',
      nameLocaleKey: 'PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_2',
      winAmount: 10,
      patterns: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Prize 3',
      nameLocaleKey: 'PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_3',
      winAmount: 10,
      patterns: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Prize 4',
      nameLocaleKey: 'PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_4',
      winAmount: 10,
      patterns: [Array]
    },
    {
      name: 'Full house',
      nameLocaleKey: 'PRIZES.BINGO_75.PRIZE_5',
      winAmount: 10,
      patterns: [Array]
    }
  ],
  tickets: { price: 10, quantity: 72, grid: { cols: [Object], rows: [Object] } },
  callout: { numbersCount: 25 }
}
```

In node.js patterns look like [Array], but if display each pattern it look like:

```
[
{type: 'HORIZONTAL', count: 1},
{type: 'VERTICAL', count: 1},
{type: 'DIAGONAL', count: 1}
]
```

Comment: Can you show what `console.log(currentGameConfig)` prints?

Comment: @lpizzinidev, I have added a config view